# How to have parent method accept additional arguments compared to child method without linting issues

Tags: python, inheritance, pylint

I have a data structure where different objects are considered "equivalent" if certain parameters/arguments match. I want to implement a method in the parent class that does some of the checks that must apply to all children in order to make them equivalent. In addition, depending on the child class, some additional checks need to pass as well.

I implemented the following structure:

```
class Parent(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def isequivalent(
        self,
        other,
        checks: list[bool],
    ) -> bool:

        if not <generic condition1>:
            return False
        if not <generic condition2>:
            return False
        # etc

        for check in checks():
            if not check:
                return False

        return True



class Child(Parent):

    def isequivalent(
        self,
        other,
    ) -> bool:
        checks = [
            <specific condition 1>,
            <specific condition 2>,
            # etc
        ]
        return super().isequivalent(other, checks)
```

This works fine in terms of functionality. However, I get a "pylint: arguments-differ" message from my linter. I've tried to look up the correct implementation (e.g. [here](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/arguments-differ.html)), but all the examples are where the child has more arguments and the solutions don't fit my situation.

I don't want to add a `checks: list | None = None` optional argument to the child methods, as I don't want it to be accessible/editable when instantiating the class.

Note also that the parent class is an `ABC`, so there will never be an instance of the parent itself.

Is there a correct way to implement this, apart from just overruling the linter?

Comment: What is the `raise_` parameter that you supply? Did you just mean to call it with `(other, checks)`?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to remove that. I simplified the code compared to what I have in the actual implementation (option to either raise error or return false). I now edited my question without that.

Comment: I think you simply need to rename the method in the parent (and remove the @abstractmethod) to indicate that it is a private detail for subclasses. That way pylint can't complain.

Comment: I feel like that is the equivalent solution of adding `# pylint: disable=arguments-differ`. It feels to me like it makes sense to actually have the functions under the same name as they are dealing with the same task. Given that linting problems generally indicate that one is doing something "wrong" or at least against best practice, I am wondering what the best practice here might be. But ultimately it may just be to rename one of the two methods with a leading underscore.

Comment: You say it yourself. Linting problems indicate a design problem. Just renaming a function leaves you with proper control over your code. A comment that pylint understands is still a comment which may come back to bite you.